# Safe shutdown from Kisok mode

Tags: macos, imac

I plan to deploy a kiosk with no keyboard and mouse. Can anyone think of a way to allow safe shutdown? I think the power button will put up a user prompt that requires a keyboard or mouse. The only thing I could think of was a usb enter key. This is silly so I'm asking for help.

Comment: Is it going to be connected to the network?

Comment: Yes! However it is at a remote location so inbound communication is a no-go.

Comment: Kind of having trouble imagining what the setup looks like but there are ways to overcome NAT issues with remote admin software (having the client check in to a task server on ARD, etc.) Are you sure you need safe shutdown though? In a kiosk type configuration I can't see why you couldn't just long press power to shutdown

Comment: Imagine your business model is to put a machine in every customer location. You control the machine but not the network.
Long press is not a safe shutdown. It does not unmount the drive. I would like to avoid "no boot" situations that can happen with repeatedly shutting down a machine without unmounting the boot drive first.

Comment: I doubt forced shutdowns would do that to an idle system... maybe a longer boot up time when you turn it back on sure, but apart from losing data from unsaved files, shouldn't be a big problem (it's not the same thing as pulling the plug while it's running) Anyhow, [this app](http://pkamb.github.io/PowerKey/) might be of interest, you can remap the power button to act as the return key – hold power to get the dialogue to show up then press again to shut down

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/power-off-computer-via-power-switch-with-no-confirmation-dialog.1574612/) with applescript

```
on idle
set i to 0

tell application "System Events"

    -- Get a count of all the windows belonging to the process
    set numberOfWindows to count windows of process "loginwindow"

    -- Check each window for a "Shut Down" button....
    repeat numberOfWindows times
        set i to i + 1

        -- ....and shut down if found
        if exists button "Shut Down" of window i of process "loginwindow" then
            click button "Shut Down" of window i of process "loginwindow"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

-- How often the script checks for the window (in seconds). Change it as you see fit.
return 7
end idle
```

Haven't tested it yet, but it sounds reasonable.

edit
**Option 2**
Super simple (assuming no open applications will prompt for user interaction first)

```
tell app "System Events" to shut down
```

**Option 3** (variation on option 1)

```
tell application "System Events" to set the visible of every process to true

set white_list to {"Finder"}
set white_list to {"Shutdown"}

try
  tell application "Finder"
      set process_list to the name of every process whose visible is true
    end tell
    repeat with i fron 1 to (number of items in process_list)
      set this_process to item i of the process_list
      if this_process is not in white_list then
        tell application this_process
          quit
        end tell
        end if
    end repeat
on error
    tell application "finder"
    shutdown
    end tell
end try
delay 2
tell application "Finder"
  shut down
end tell
```